# Select multiple unique lines in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I've got a table with the following columns:

ID, sysid, x, y, z, timereceived

ID is a unique number for each row.

sysid is an ID number for a specific device (about 100 different of these)

x, y and z is data received from the device. (totally random numbers)

timereceived is a timestamp for when the data was received.

I need a SQL query to show me the last inserted row for device a, device b, device c and so on.

I've been playing around with a lot of different Select statements, but never got anything that works. I manage to get unique rows by using group by, but the rest of the information is random (or at least it feels very random).

Anyone able to help me?

There could be hundreds of thousands records in this table.

Comment: A follow-up question on the same subject; how do I rewrite the answer I got to be able to use it in a View? As it is now, the subquery makes MySQL throw #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT id, sysid, x, y, z, timereceived
      FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (  SELECT sysid, max(timereceived) as "timereceived"
                FROM tbl
            GROUP BY sysid ) most_recent
     USING (sysid, timereceived)
```

This will give you complete rows where the `timereceived` is the most recent per `sysid`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sysid, MAX(timereceived) FROM yourtable GROUP BY sysid
```

Not sure on speed because I don't have a large table to test it on. Make sure there's an index on sysid and timereceived and that would help. It may actually be faster to do a query for each one of your devices.

Comment: With this I get one row for each sysid with the latest timestamp, but no other information.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, sysid, x, y, z, MAX(timereceived) as max_time FROM `table` GROUP BY sysid
```

UPDATED:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.sysid, t1.x, t1.y, t1.z, t1.timereceived 
    FROM `table` as t1
    JOIN (
      SELECT sysid, MAX(timereceived) as max_time
      FROM `table`
      GROUP BY sysid
    ) AS t2 ON (t2.sysid = t1.sysid AND t2.max_time = t1.timereceived)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been doing so far, and at first I thought it was working, but the only thing being from the latest row for each sysid is the timestamp. The other data feels totally random with no logic to it (but I'm sure there is some logic as it is the same info every time.